# Java Simple Date Formatter parsing error

Tags: parsing, date

How to parse "Tue Jun 05 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012" text to Date in Java?
I have used format "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" But not working.

Comment: too much text and less code..

Comment: _But not working_ is not efficient to find out whats the problem here. Do share some code so that one can find out _what is not working_

Answer (score 0):

The trick that you may have missed is that you must set the locale because "Tue" or "Jun" can only be understood in English.

This works :

```
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date dt = ft.parse("Tue Jun 05 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012");
```